# Cross-platform development - Delphi 2011: How to made a Windows-tied library cross-platform?

Tags: delphi, cross-platform

As perhaps you know already, most probably the next version of Delphi will be [cross-platform](http://wings-of-wind.com/2009/09/11/kylix-2011/). Also, here are some [polls](http://wings-of-wind.com/2009/09/08/where-do-you-want-to-go-tommorow-cross-platform-native-code/) on the matter.

While writing a cross-compiler isn't a thing which interests us very much now, porting a library which was/is Windows-tied to multiple platforms, certainly does.

You can think, for example at VCL (Delphi's standard library). While it was designed for Windows only, it has value in it, and, of course, there are huge codebases which depend on it.

**The question is:**
Which would be the best approach to made an application / library cross-platform aware *ensuring* a smooth conversion / upgrade path (as much as possible of course)?

I stress it again, we are not interested which is the best way to do cross-platform development **only** (there were questions on this theme). We are interested also in yet another requirement: *The old code base / installations management.*

PS: Experiences and/or methodologies from similar situations with other languages (eg. C/C++) which are regarded as *standard practices* are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compatible with the old code is a huge price to pay!

Comment: "Compatible with the old code is a huge price to pay!" - oh, yes. This is the gist of the problem.

Comment: These days, we have many XProject argument, but nobody can submit some good ideas or feasible solutions. I worry that this situation is the same in Embarcadero(I hope that my worry is unnecessary). Perhaps Embarcadero should disclose more information about cross-platform.

Comment: @Ertugrul Tamer Kara: You must be confusing this with **64 Bit** =)

Comment: For a start, setting the library, search, browsing paths is a nightmare.

Comment: I wonder is somebody out there is really doing serious cross-platform programming with Delphi. Delphi XE7 seems as unstable as any other post-XE version.

Answer (score 4):

**Visual component developer's perspective:**

Add levels of functionality to your code, so as to be able to add another platform without changing the "Core" of the component. 
The compiler hopefully will have a platform switch. (Preferable more than one, working in conjunction with each other. ex. Windows/ARM, Windows/386,  OSX/Cacao/386, Linux/Gnome/386).

The Layout structure might look something like this.

- ComponentJ.pas
- Linux\ComponentJ.pas
- Linux\Gnome\ComponentJ.pas
- Linux\KDE\ComponentJ.pas
- OSX\ComponentJ.pas
- 386\ComponentJ.pas
- ARM\ComponentJ.pas

**As an Application Developer:**

I'll start by moving all WIN API calls in my code into a group of libraries in a Windows directory as to be able to IFDEF it at library level and translate it into another platform I'd like to support as soon as the compiler becomes available, but only as I come across them.)
This will also add the possibility to add adapters easier for the new platforms.
It in any case is good practice to remove possible dependencies into a central place.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO you can't build a xplatform Delphi and ensure a smooth transition for current VCL applications. It won't work. VCL was (luckily, because it allowed for great applications) designed with Windows in mind, and trying to design a compatible library working on a different platform would just mean longer development cycles and lots of compromises. The outcome will be a library noone would wish to use. Look at what happened to VCL.NET: it was the wrong choice. And it was working on the same OS!

We know that targeting non-Windows platform with *native* applications needs a native GUI library. We don't care about creating a GUI from scratch, for our application it's the way to go, we don't need Windows GUIs with all their standards under a different OS using different standards - we need to be able to code a fully native GUI for the target OS.
Other applications may survive a GUI porting, but in the long run you don't get a real xplatform tool - you get a tool that may compile for other platforms but brings one platform paradigms to others - and it will also be not welcome by "native" developers on other platforms. If you're a Linux or Mac developer, why should you learn how to work with a library that carries its Windows inheritance to your platform? You'd find it a pain in the ass. If Embarcadero wants to sell XDelphi outside actual developers base, it has to offer much more than a new CLX.

Comment: +1, very good answer. From my experience with wxWidgets I would even go as far as saying that for optimum platform-native GUIs it would be best to split applications into a non-visual part, realized with a cross-platform solution, and a single-platform GUI on top of it. Using GTK, Cocoa and for example Delphi it would be easiest to create platform-conforming GUI with newest controls - cross-platform solutions take time to support new stuff, and often force to use the lowest common denominator only.

Comment: I agree that an xplatform solution should do the best it can to separate UI logic from non-visual application logic. It could be a little more complex to code that actual "event driven" paradigm - I already use UI events with caution, avoiding to code there what don't belong to the UI-, but it will allow to "plug" different, native UIs to the underlying logic, having to rewrite only the former.

Comment: No, I'm not thinking at 2nd VCL in the way in which VCL.NET was. But this doesn't mean that it cannot be a smooth, incremental transition. I think that this VCL 2.0 should allow mainly appropriate *tooling* to do this conversion and in the future building from scratch x-platform solutions.

Comment: Guess any "conversion tool" won't work but with simpler applications - and probably if you didn't use any third party control (and our application nowadays uses almost exclusively Developer Express controls to deliver a more modern interface than Delphi allows).
IMHO it's better Embarcadero invests its resource to deliver good libraries to develop good native applications on the target platforms than trying to port existing ones in a barely working way
IMHO it would be wasted time. "Incremental transition" IMHO will doom the library future, being forced to support a WinVCL compatibility.

Comment: Good answer! IMHO the only "complete" compatibility should be in the RTL and in the "non visual" components not directly tied to Windows. For example "Windows Service" application could not be ported "as is" into the new XDelphi, but the same "Way to do things" could be nice. The LinuxVCL/MacOSVCL should be NATIVE for that OS. Complete GUI compatibility is not the right way. Hi performance compiler, RTL and hi performance Native-VCL is the right way.

Answer (score 4):

I will pull from some ancient experience in making a code base cross compilable between windows and dos (Delphi 1/Turbo Pascal 7).  The rule of thumb was to separate code into multiple units.  Try to code WITHOUT using windows, messages or any visual components.  If you find you need to make a call to one of these, then place that call in another unit and write a proxy (abstract class that you descend from works well) to dispatch the calls through.  When a cross compatible version is released, all that you should have to do is code the other side of the proxy for the new target.

If you're designing a form based system, then try to stick with as many of the standard components as possible.  NEVER implement any "business" rules directly in an event, instead place them in another unit and call into the other unit to perform the logic.

Now, there will definitely be changes required to get your final project cross compatible, but by following these simple patterns you should be able to greatly reduce the amount of work it will take.

Comment: Yes, good one. But perhaps it would be better if for this you would have support from IDE? (Wizards, tooling etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Experience so far has shown that the best way to get a Delphi app compatible with future versions is to stick to pure Delphi components, and use nothing third party. Such an app will probably suck, but that's how it seems to me. I use lots of third party components, and the apps are great and successful. But the chances of them moving to this future too are not certain, and that may cause problems with such changes, but I'd rather have a great app now and have the problem than have a poor app now and not need to worry about it.

Comment: But who want's their app to suck?!  Some of the third-party products, e.g. DevEx Grid can add a lot of value to an application so replacing it in this example with plain TDBGrid would simply make the application worse and less attractive to customers which is the bottom line.  I'd rather wait and see what DevEx do with DelphiX.

I could see replacing third-party components that have an analogue VCL component of similar capability being a good step though.

Comment: As I said, I use additional components too - I don't want my apps to suck. But that's probably where you are with vanilla Delphi apps. (Though the more recent Delphi's have made big improvements.)

Answer (score 1):

Compromises should not be done too much to make VCL compatible with Linux and Mac. Windows is VCL's root. I'll prefer a new and very clean GUI framework, even though without any backward compatibility. Make VCL fatter and fatter isn't a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

1. make a cross-platform Pascal compiler
2. make a cross-platform RTL
3. put the QT on top

Well, look at [freepascal](http://freepascal.org) and [lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it. All .NET looks the same to me providing we don't use any third party.
   Delphi using standard control is already fully functional but your app would look
   like thousands of others.

I think Embar should go for PDA, IPhone, Andriod as Windows desktop already eat about
   98% of the market.

Mac is expensive and Linux is no cost at all.  No use to go for Mac and Linux. Not worth 
   the investment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, aside the things said - thanks all - I do think that there we need some *additional* things:

- we need tooling to do the necessary conversions
- we need tooling to help us in programming against a (some form of) MVC pattern

Answer (score 0):

Simply pick the latest 4.6 QT and add good integration betwen the Pascal and the QT library.
They have done it before (in the Kylix times). The QT is such powerfull these days.

I believe that QT is even better then VCL and at least 10 times more frequently updated and fixed.

So the plan is simple:

1. make a cross-platform Pascal compiler
2. make a cross-platform RTL
3. put the QT on top

and you will have a first-class natively looking applications on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

1. Make cross platform compiler (OS x/Linux/ embedded solutions?/ symbian?). Maybe add ability to compile/convert pascal code into portable c/c++ code to build then on embedded platforms.
2. RTL have to be separated into cross-platform layer and native layer (as for JCL).
3. Add new core components for cross-platform compatibility and native components for each supported platform (QT for ex)
4. Add translation utilities to create/convert between platform's components, for ex: to convert pure windows form into mac os x cocoa's form.
5. All windows hierarchy of components have to be only upgraded to support x64 with maximum backward compatibility. All cross-platform component have to be in parallel hierarchy.
6. Next version of cross platform solution can be refactored and can include migration/convertion utility. Due to minimum codebase of cross-platform solutions, hierarchy and classes for cross platform can be heavily changed from version to version to achieve best architecture.

sorry for my English - not a native language (Russian is)!

Answer (score -1):

1. Make C/C++/Delphi compilers that targets OSX/Linux
2. Make C/C++ compiler that can be Boosted
3. Write new VCL-Presentation Foundation (VGScene/WPF alike)
   it should not be backward compatibile! Delphi IDE should be
   written with such VCL-PF
4. Component Library should stay as it is (but with improved Data-Binding)
5. Only provide VCL 64-bit for Win64

Is this a problem?